# Avid Shorty 4 Carbon Brake Pads

Tags: brakes, carbon

I have Avid Shorty 4 brakes on a cross bike. I would like to use zipp 303 carbon wheels, but I am not sure about brake pads. The brake pads on there now are a combined cartridge and pad set. You cannot replace the pads. Any recommendations on pad holders and brake pads for carbon wheels that would fit well on Avid Shorty 4 brakes?

Thanks-

Comment: I seem to recall people running V-brake pads on the Avid Shorty line, though the website says that they're road cartridges (though the picture looks like a V-brake pad). In any case, Kool stop makes some good pads, but make sure your pads are carbon specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your current pads are V-brake style, these pads should work well: http://www.swissstop.com/rimbrakes/rxplus/yellowking/

As for the pad holders, it's not easy to find them sold without pads, nor with carbon pads.  That's too bad, but you can buy these anyway and use the pads on another bike: http://www.koolstop.com/english/v_type2holder.html

Comment: I had forgotten to come back and answer this, but your answer is what I did. I purchased RxPlus pads. What brought everything together for me was http://www.swissstop.com/support/installation/rxplus/  I did not realize the  pads I had already purchased as replacements actually had holders with removable pads. You just need to remove the pins. The holders I have are like this http://cdn.modernbike.com/Product_Images/large_22376.jpg  The stock Avid Shorty 4 pads do not have holders. Thanks.